# In AIX 7.1 Apache modules not building as shared

Tags: apache2, aix

I want all my modules built with a .so extension so that they are shared.  However, all my modules are building with a .la extension.  Here are the contents of the module directory:

```
httpd.exp                libmod_proxy_ajp.a       libmod_speling.a         mod_info.la              mod_proxy_scgi.la
libmod_cern_meta.a       libmod_proxy_balancer.a  libmod_ssl.a             mod_proxy.la             mod_rewrite.la
libmod_dbd.a             libmod_proxy_connect.a   libmod_vhost_alias.a     mod_proxy_ajp.la         mod_speling.la
libmod_deflate.a         libmod_proxy_ftp.a       mod_cern_meta.la         mod_proxy_balancer.la    mod_ssl.la
libmod_expires.a         libmod_proxy_http.a      mod_dbd.la               mod_proxy_connect.la     mod_vhost_alias.la
libmod_info.a            libmod_proxy_scgi.a      mod_deflate.la           mod_proxy_ftp.la
libmod_proxy.a           libmod_rewrite.a         mod_expires.la           mod_proxy_http.la
```

Here is my configure command:

```
./configure \
--with-mpm=prefork \
--with-ssl=/opt/freeware \
--enable-cern-meta \
--enable-dbd \
--enable-deflate \
--enable-expires \
--enable-info \
--enable-proxy \
--enable-rewrite \
--enable-speling \
--enable-ssl \
--enable-vhost-alias \
--enable-mods-shared="cern_meta dbd deflate expires info proxy rewrite speling ssl    vhost_alias"
```

I have done this many times in the past on AIX 5.2, 5.3 and 6.1 without issue.

Answer (score 0):

`.la` files are [libtool's library control file syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Linking-libraries.html).  Notice they are really just small scripts.  Check for your shared library objects inside the `.libs` directory.    You might also explicitly tell `configure` that you want shared libraries with `--enable-shared`